# Multiple Elastic Search Entries in Config

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

When I run the following command I get two entries in our config for Elastic Search 7 and 5

```
php bin/magento config:show | grep -Ei 'elastic|system/full_page_cache/caching_application|varnish|catalog/search/engine'

catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname - serverhostname
catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port - 42630
catalog/search/elasticsearch7_index_prefix - magento2
catalog/search/elasticsearch7_enable_auth - 0
catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_timeout - 15
**catalog/search/elasticsearch5_server_hostname - differentserverhostname**
```

Why is `elasticsearch5` appearing and how can I remove this line. Everything on the admin side is set to Elastic Search 7.0+

Answer (score 1):

Just mentioning another case where this might happen.

I faced this issue due to live search being installed on my instance.
As per DevDocs, **Elasticsearch** should be disabled if **live search** is installed, or if you are using elasticsearch and have live search installed, then disable it.

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_LiveSearchAdapter Magento_LiveSearchStorefrontPopover
```

[check the docs to live search](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-merchant-services/live-search/onboard/install.html?lang=en#method-2)

Answer (score 0):

Config for `elasticsearch5` is saved when you setup/upgrade Magento version or you saved config for Elastic Search on an older Magento version.

It is safe to delete these records, you can delete them from `core_config_data`: go to Mysql, and run the below command:

```
DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%catalog/search/elasticsearch5%';
```

Comment: Thanks. It must have come from an older version of Magento. I resolved the issue by upgrading to a newer version of Magento. After running the command again the record for elasticsearch5 was gone.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers!